# A Word for someone who has a high tolerance for doing menial, monotonous tasks?

Tags: word-request

A Word for someone who has a high tolerance or skill in doing menial, monotonous, or repetitive, low education requiring tasks?

Comment: A related word (not necessarily indicating someone with high tolerance) is *drudge*: “one whose work is routine and boring”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some contexts, you could say **trooper**:

"She's been sorting through those papers for three days now. She's such a trooper."